# Remote SSH command with MySQL won't work, but the statement itself does

Tags: mysql, ssh

I want to achieve that some MySQL commands are run on a remote server to remove all tables from a database. Therefore I connect with SSH (SSH logs in using public key) and run a mysql command, all in a bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh user@example.com "mysql -uadmin -p\$(cat /etc/psa/.psa.shadow) exdb<<EOFMYSQL
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
SET @tables = NULL;
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(table_schema, '.', table_name) INTO @tables
  FROM information_schema.tables 
  WHERE table_schema = 'exdb';

SET @tables = CONCAT('DROP TABLE ', @tables);
PREPARE stmt FROM @tables;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
EOFMYSQL"
```

The MySQL part itself succeeds, when I connect via SSH to my remote server, log into mysql and issue the commands.
However, in this script, I get:

> ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 8: You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the
>   right syntax to use near 'NULL' at line 1

I think this error has to do with the quoting of `-p\$(cat /etc/psa/.psa.shadow)`, however I could not figure out how to resolve this problem.

I'd be glad if someone could point me where the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have no tables in the database, so you're getting no result from the select and the `GROUP_CONCAT` returns NULL, and the concat of `DROP TABLE` with `NULL` is... `NULL`.

Preparing a statement using `NULL` as a statement will give your error.

[An SQLfiddle to show the problem](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7bc0e/9).

Comment: I was so blind. With testing if the SQL really works, I cleared out all tables and such, the subsequent tests all went wrong like you described. Thanks!